# Sculpt Mode Matcap rotation

Tags: sculpting, matcaps

The title is pretty self explainatory.

I looked up everywhere but I can't even seem to find anybody asking about it. It's pretty strange considering it's one of most basic sculpting functions.

So back to the question. Can you quickly rotate a matcap in blender. If not then is there an addon that can do that?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

With the default functionality it's only possible to flip the matcap horizontally.

[image: Flip matcap]